# ReactiveCocoa: Subscribe only to new values

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, reactive-cocoa

I've created an event subscriber in viewDidLoad, as follows:

```
[RACObserve(_authenticationView.passwordInput.textField, text) subscribeNext:^(NSString* text)
{
     //handle this
}];
```

This fires whenever the textField.text property *changes* (expected), however it also fires once when *created*, or for the intitial value, which is not what I want.

Of course I could filter this out, but I only want to filter the first event out. How do I do this?

**Requirements:**

- If the password has a *new* empty value, present a validation message (can't proceed password empty).
- If the password has a new non-empty value, talk to remote client.

. . so what's the cleanest way to do this?

Comment: I'm not ReactiveCocoa user but as far as I understood from the docs of ReactiveCocoa, you should add self(in this case view controller) as an observer and create a new property for NSString * then observe it. In the event method you must set textfield property.

Comment: ReactiveCocoa provides a helper `rac_textSignal` method that may be more reliable than observing `text`, since `UITextField`s aren't guaranteed to be KVO compliant for that key (as far as I understand).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use different approaches:

1. `-skip:1` to skip first value.

```
[[RACObserve(_authenticationView.passwordInput.textField, text) skip:1] subscribeNext:^(NSString* text) {
    //handle this
}];
```

---

2. `-ignore:nil` to skip initial nil value.

```
[[RACObserve(_authenticationView.passwordInput.textField, text) ignore:nil] subscribeNext:^(NSString* text) {
    //handle this
}];
```

---

3. `-distinctUntilChanged` to skip new values, that equal previous.

```
[[RACObserve(_authenticationView.passwordInput.textField, text) distinctUntilChanged] subscribeNext:^(NSString* text) {
    //handle this
}];
```

Answer (score 21):

If you just want to skip the first value, just stick a `-skip:1` in there:

```
[[RACObserve(_authenticationView.passwordInput.textField, text) skip:1] subscribeNext:^(NSString* text)
{
     //handle this
}];
```

Comment: ...and this is the canonical way to do this, recommended in the 2.0 migration guide: https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md ...also you're a core ReactiveCocoa contributor, so you knew that already...